# VueJS + Webpack + dynamic CSS

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js

how I can dynamicaly load CSS file on VueJS (SPA) application?

**Short scenario**

- Application starts and submit request to backend server for CSS file name by url address
- Apllication get response from backend server with css filename params

Then i need call something whats load new CSS file by response data.

We used this for web-site branding (CSS are depends on actual domain - but site is installed on one hosting). This CSS file can be located on our server (/assets/css/xx.css) or on other servers.

**Short snippet from Vue component:**

```
loadCssRequest(location.href).then(function(reponse){
    // something whats load css by response.css_code
});
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject css to head of component

```
loadCssRequest(location.href).then(function(reponse){
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.innerHTML = reponse;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
});
```

Or if you have css path on another server (for example `/assets/css/xx.css`)

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href', '/assets/css/xx.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```